# android - Fragment does not get arrayList from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, getter-setter

I've a MainActivity that provides a ViewPager, and in this Activity there's a method that fills an ArrayList once app has obtained permissions. 
I pass this ArrayList with a setter but the Fragment does not consider the value passed 

 **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
                mArraySongs = listAllSongs();
                listFragment.setSongsList(mArraySongs);
                Log.d("test arraylist in activity: ", Integer.toString(mArraySongs.size()));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**ListFragment.java**

```
public void setSongsList(ArrayList<Song> songsList) {
    this.mSongList = songsList;
    Log.d("test fragment setSongsList", Integer.toString(mSongList.size()));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mInflater = inflater;
    mContext = container.getContext();
    mContainer = container;
    Log.d("test fragment onCreateView", Integer.toString(mSongList.size()));

    //check if ArrayList is empty
    if(mSongList == null || mSongList.isEmpty()){
        rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.error_no_songs, mContainer, false);
    } else showListView();
    return rootView;
}
```

**Logcat**

```
05-06 01:36:50.118 5272-5272/com.sebb.vilify D/test fragment onCreateView: 0
05-06 01:36:50.817 5272-5272/com.sebb.vilify D/test fragment setSongsList: 7
05-06 01:36:50.817 5272-5272/com.sebb.vilify D/test arraylist in activity: 7
```

How can I take the value passed with that setter method?

Comment: Logs show you already have it. Maybe you're not displaying it.

Comment: make mSongList static in your fragment

Comment: @Pravin it didn't work :/

Comment: as you can see from your logs, the `onCreateView` is called before you set the song list in the fragment.

Comment: Once you've got the data, you need to tell fragment to update its view as it has been already created. in setSongList, either initialize the adapter and set it or notify it depending on its state(adapter==null)

Answer (score 0):

Call your showListView method from setSongList.

Comment: it gives a NullPointerException

Comment: Check for null first like you do in on create. Alternatively make a getter in your main activity for the arraylist and access it directly like this: ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSongList();

Comment: Fragment shows its elements only when I go on another fragment in tabLayout and then I go back, in other words: when app is launched onCreateView is called and takes an empty arraylist from main activity, only after a few millisecs the activity's arraylist contains objects.